# Solidity if else 2 things how to

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix

So I got an if-else statement if the price of eth is the same as stop order sell will be = to true, but I also want to do if the price is same or bigger then limit also sell = true. If price under limit it should be false, or if the price was not stop order. So I need if price == StopOrder **or** price >= LimitOrder in one if statment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical logic operators can be used in Solidity. So:

`if (price == StopOrder || price == LimitOrder) { do stuff }`